# PowerShell - AD users from Primary group plus either of two Secondary groups

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0, membership, active-directory-group

The script here:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Get-users-who-b0420fe1

will return results for users that exist in a primary group, plus either of two secondary groups (thanks to OP zperryz for the code).  Below is my version of this script so far.

I'd like to add conditions for disabled users, and users that are in a specific "hold" OU.  In another script, I've been able to do this like so (obviously a snippet, not the whole script):

```
| where {$_.Enabled -ne $False} `
| where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*HOLD OU*"} `
```

I'm just not sure where to "inject" these into the script below.  (A future modification would then return more information, like DisplayName, Enabled & DistinguishedName, instead of just the logon.)

If anyone has some advice, I'd greatly appreciate it!  Here's the script as it stands today:

```
$ADgroup1 = "VPN Front Door"
$ADgroup2 = "VPN Full Access"
$ADgroup3 = "VPN Restricted Access"

get-adgroupmember $ADgroup1 `
  | ForEach-Object {if(((GET-ADUSER –Identity $_.SamAccountName –Properties MemberOf `
  | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1') -eq "$ADgroup2" -or "$ADgroup3"){$_.SamAccountName `
  | Out-File -append -filepath C:\Users\3Jake\Desktop\VPN_Users.txt}}
```

Thank you!

**FINAL VERSION, all tarted up with comments:**

As-is, this is designed to run in the console, but it should be easy to update to spit out a file if needed.

```
#  Define Variables
$ADgroup1 = "VPN Front Door"
$ADgroup2 = "VPN Full Access"
$ADgroup3 = "VPN Restricted Access"
$vpnGroups = $ADgroup2, $ADgroup3

#  Collect users in $ADgroup1
#  Also pass user properties forward
$UsersFound = (
  Get-ADGroupMember $ADgroup1 |
  Get-ADUser -Properties MemberOf, Name, SamAccountName, Company |

  #  Ignore disabled users & those in the "On HOLD" OU
  Where {
    $_.Enabled -ne $False -and
    $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*HOLD OU*'
  } |

  #  Compare users in $ADgroup1 to the ones in $ADgroup2 and $ADgroup3
  select Name, SamAccountName, Company,
         @{n='Groups';e={$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select -Expand Name}} |
  Where { $groups = @($_.Groups); $vpnGroups | Where { $groups -contains $_ } }
  )

  #  Display count
Write-Host "Total = " $UsersFound.Count

  #  Prompt to show user info
$YN = Read-Host "Show Users? (Y/N)"
if ($YN -eq 'Y')
{
$UsersFound |
select Name, SamAccountName, Company | 
Sort-Object name, company | 
Out-GridView
}
else {exit}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should unravel that convoluted `if` statement. Something like this would be far more readable (and far more maintainable):

```psh
$vpnGroups = $ADgroup2, $ADgroup3

Get-ADGroupMember $ADgroup1 | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf |
    select SamAccountName,
           @{n='Groups';e={$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select -Expand Name}} |
    ? { $groups = @($_.Groups); $vpnGroups | ? { $groups -contains $_ } } |
    select -Expand SamAccountName |
    Out-File -Append -Filepath 'C:\Users\3Jake\Desktop\VPN_Users.txt'
}
```

You don't even need the `ForEach-Object` loop, because `Get-ADUser` can read directly from the pipeline:

```psh
$vpnGroups = $ADgroup2, $ADgroup3

Get-ADGroupMember $ADgroup1 |
  Get-ADUser -Properties MemberOf |
  select SamAccountName,
         @{n='Groups';e={$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select -Expand Name}} |
  ? { $groups = @($_.Groups); $vpnGroups | ? { $groups -contains $_ } } |
  select -Expand SamAccountName |
  Out-File -Filepath 'C:\Users\3Jake\Desktop\VPN_Users.txt'
```

With that you can simply insert your additional filter(s) after the `Get-ADUser`:

```psh
Get-ADGroupMember $ADgroup1 |
  Get-ADUser -Properties MemberOf |
  ? {
    $_.Enabled -ne $False -and
    $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*HOLD OU*'
  } |
  select SamAccountName,
         @{n='Groups';e={$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select -Expand Name}} |
  ? { $groups = @($_.Groups); $vpnGroups | ? { $groups -contains $_ } } |
  select -Expand SamAccountName |
  Out-File -Filepath 'C:\Users\3Jake\Desktop\VPN_Users.txt'
```

Comment: Cool, thanks @AnsgarWiechers - I'm all for detangling the original code!  This is MUCH more readable.

Comment: @ AnsgarWiechers I sure will - right now I'm getting some errors with this and wondering if I have a typo somewhere.  I'll try posting the code and errors in the comments below:

Comment: ok thanks, I have it updated in the original question now - it looks much better up there! :)

Comment: @3Jake Ah, my mistake. There's a `;` missing before the `e=`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I added the ; and also had to remove the comma from the line above - it runs in my ISE console, but will not output to a file.  It looks like it doesn't care about anything in the last two lines; I tried moving them into the last set of curly-braces but so far no joy.  It will output to the screen and then create a blank .txt.  But truthfully I don't care, this is way farther than I was before!!  Any way I could get it to provide a count of the results? Put the whole thing into a variable ($Total) and then use "Write-Host $Total.count"?

Comment: What makes you think you had to remove the comma? Put it back where it was. Removing it disconnects the pipeline. Empty input to the second half of course produces empty output.

Comment: Yeah, I was having trouble and trying to figure it out on my own - it certainly makes sense that if I disconnect the pipeline, then obviously I wouldn't get any output beyond that point :)  Thanks for pointing out my mistake.  My issue is that when I run the code from my update above, WITH the comma and the semicolon in place, I get no results.  Nothing in the console window and a blank .txt.  There should be no users who are both disabled AND in the "hold OU", so I also tried changing the "-and" to an "-or" (and back) but no difference.

Comment: @3Jake Replace everything after the first `select` with a `Format-List` (so your statement ends with `... | selcect SamAccountName, @{n='Groups';e={...}} | Format-List *`) and check if the group lists actually contain one of the VPN groups.

Comment: Thanks again @AnsgarWiechers - changing the line to `@{n='Groups';e={$_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | select -Expand Name}} | format-list *`, the resulting list of users each have one or more of the VPN groups listed.  Just trying to think it through, I then reverted that line and moved the Format-List down to the next line: `? { $vpnGroups | ? { @($_.Groups) -contains $_ } } |  format-list *` at which point no results were returned.  Does this indicate that the script thinks there are no users in the "primary" group who also exist in one of the "secondary" groups?

Comment: @3Jake I'm an idiot. The current object variable in the nested pipeline (inside the `Where-Object` scriptblock) is not the user object, but the name of the current VPN group, which of course does not have a `Groups` property, so you never get a match. *\*slaps self\** See updated answer.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the explanation!  The updated code is perfect - on a test user, if I have only the primary group, it doesn't show.  If I have the primary and either of the secondaries, it does.  If I then move it to the Hold OU, it doesn't, and if I move it back, but disable it, it also doesn't.  Perfect!  Marking this as the answer.

Comment: You've helped a lot already, but I'd like to report other info too - is there a way to show "name" & "company" as well?  I've tried adding them to the "get" and "select" statements to pass them through, but not sure how to work it into "select -Expand".  Also working on a count by wrapping the whole enchilada in parens and assigning to a variable ($Result), then using "$Result.count" - which DOES work, but at this point I ONLY get the count, not the list of users :)  If you have any advice left for this project, I'd be grateful - if not, thanks again for all your great advice!

Comment: @3Jake There most likely is a way, but you should ask that as a new question.